# Replace assignment with deferred assignment

Tags: javascript, angularjs, promise, angular-promise

In my angular.js page I extend $scope with all attributes I need. 
Before, I simply extended $scope with

```
angular.extend($scope,{
    myAttr : aService.getValues()
});
```

However, turns out I have to add a promise (angular file access) to `aService.getValues`. Hence, I cant keep the above syntax but have to replace it with

```
angular.extend($scope,{
myAttr : null
});
aService.getValues().then(function(values){$scope.myAttr = values;})
```

That's annoying because I have to replace quite a bit of code and am afraid to add bugs. Any alternatives?

Answer (score 1):

The only thing I can suggest is a slightly prettier re-doing of your own solution:

```
aService.getValues().then(function(values) {
  angular.extend($scope, {
    myAttr: values
  })
});
```

Is it critical that `$scope` is extended synchronously? If it is, I don't see any way of feeding asynchronous data into it any other way.

**EDIT**

If you're reworking your logic, consider using `$stateProvider` with a `resolve` property: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki (Scroll down to the section that talks about resolve). Long story short, everything in the `resolve` must run before the state controller is initialized. This way you can do all your async operations in the resolve, and only let it load after you have everything you need.

Comment: It is a key to initialize my whole view controller. I believe I will have to reshuffle the init logic in the controller then. Thanks for re-doing the code, looks better now :)

Comment: Added a suggested fix.

Comment: Oh great, that makes sense. However, is that applicable in the controler where I could assign values to $scope.myAttr ?

Comment: Well, yes, I think -- if I'm understanding you correctly, yes. The `resolve` should not be in the controller, but rather your config file (aka where you do `angular.module('myApp').config()...run()`). The code in the resolve will run before the controller initializes.